# How to get a Gmail API instance from firebase Authentication

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, gmail-api

I have a Firebase Google login working just great. I want my app to be able to send emails (Gmail API) from the current logged user's account. That's why I added and extra scope on the provider before generating the auth instance, and it actually request for sending email permission when the user logs in for the first time (According to [Gmail API Docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)). Like this:

```
var proveedor= new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
proveedor.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send")
this.login.auth.signInWithPopup(proveedor).then(res=>{
        obj.appCtrl.getRootNavs()[0].push(TabsPage)
      }).catch(function (err){
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Cool so far. What I need to know is how to get a Gmail API instance from this firebase login, so I can send the emails and stuff. I know I can get the access token from that instance(`this.login.auth.currentUser.getToken()`), so maybe it could be used to create the instance I need

I'm using AngularFire which is the official lib for angular and firebase, and also I'm working on Ionic for a Progressive Web App (Browser platform).